# Is it contradictory to submit a form with $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am currently working on an MVC application where I use a lot of jQuery and html forms. However, recently I have noticed that these seem to contradict each other somewhat...

For example, I have to prevent the forms default submit to process my AJAX call, otherwise the server gets called twice which leads me to question the idea of using AJAX to submit the form. Wouldn't it be better instead to just hook the `$.ajax` call to an `<input type="button" />` than an `<input type="submit" />`?

So, is it contradictory to have a form that is submitted through ajax?

Comment: What do you mean by "contradictory"? What do you feel is contradicting?

Comment: I felt that the submit of a form through the submit process and the ajax process are contradicting each other as the default submit always takes precedence unless you prevent the default before making the ajax call.

Comment: If your client supports AJAX is there a need to force them to make a round trip to the server to fetch an entire new page just to display a thank you message or check the status of something? I myself would use AJAX to submit the data and fetch back either HTML or JSON depending on my usage. Unless you preventDefault on the form submit you'll get duplicate submissions. The idea is to code so that it degrades gracefully. You might bind to the form submit, check if AJAX is enabled, and if it is preventDefault and then do your AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you would put the ajax call on a submit button is so there is a natural fallback if the user has javascript disabled. You should have your backend logic detect if the request is an ajax request or just a straight up submit and be able to either send the data back if it's ajax or process the request the 'old school' way if not.

Edit: For context.

```
<form action="/processForm.php" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then your jQuery could look like this

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do your stuff
});
```

If the user has disabled javascript, the form will just submit to /processForm.php like normal.

You can detect if the form was sent via ajax or not with the following php (I don't know if that's what you're using, but it's what I've got).

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  /* handle ajax here */
}else{
  /* handle normal submit here */
}
```

Comment: How would I implement it as a natural fallback, currently I must prevent the action so the ajax takes precedence which means there is no fallback. Is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: If the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, then the JS that prevents the standard form submission won't fire. So you really don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: To detect if AJAX is enabled: $.support.ajax  and a full example would be $('#categoryFilter').submit(function(event){ if($.support.ajax) { event.preventDefault(); /* Put my AJAX HERE */ }});

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that it's "contradictory". It certainly isn't necessary to use a `<form>` element when submitting a form via ajax, but you still may want to use one for semantic purposes.

And yes, i'd just use an `<input type="button" />` rather than `type="submit"` because that way you want have to prevent the default form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

You can make it a fallback when the user doesn't have javascript enabled so the form is submited to the server and the user can still use your web page.

For this your backend needs to be aware if it is an ajax call.
I see you are using jQuery, jQuery ajax sends a header `x_request_with: xmlhttprequest`, and if you use PHP in the backend you can capture that in `$_SERVER['http_x_request_with']`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your trying to do.
Generally speaking I try to use  and then handle
the call with $.ajax() ... but sometime that wont work with asp.net mvc. For example if you are uploading a file, asp.net validation chokes. To get around that I I use the ajaxForm plugin and use that to wrap a standard form.